# Using contour integration to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2 \cos (x) \ln (x) + \pi \sin (x)}{x^2+4} \, \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to use contour integration to show that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2 \cos (x) \log (x) + \pi \sin (x)}{x^2+4} \, \mathrm  dx = \frac{\pi \log (2)}{2e^{2}}.$$

The recommendation in the textbook I'm reading is to integrate the function $$f(z) = \frac{e^{iz} \log(-iz)}{z^{2}+4}$$ around an indented contour that consists of the real axis from $-R$ to $R$, along with the upper half of the circle $|z|=R$.

The fact that $f(z)$ involves $\log(-iz)$ and not simply $\log (z)$ makes me a bit uneasy.

I think we would want to place the branch cut along the negative imaginary axis so that it doesn't intersect the contour.

Would that mean $- \pi  < \arg(-iz) \le  \pi$?

**EDIT**:

I converted the rest of my question into an answer.

Comment: Choose the logarithmic branch of the non-positive imaginary numbers (instead of the more usual non-positive real ones)

Comment: Isn't that the one I choose?

Comment: Yup, I missed that and didn't read the rest...:) But it's that you seemed to have issues with the argument. At the end you got the result, tough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bit backwards. If you want the branch cut to be downwards (-ve imaginary axis, located at $\arg z = -\pi/2,3\pi/2,\cdots$) then you want a $(-\pi/2,3\pi/2)$ range for $\arg z$, agreed.

Now the discontinuity is at $-i$. Hence $\arg(-iz)$ is discontinuous at $(-i)(-i)=-1$. Accordingly we will take a $(-\pi,\pi)$ type interval.

- For $\mathbb R \ni z>0$ we have $\arg(-i\times z)=\arg(-i) = -i\pi/2$.
- For $\mathbb R \ni z<0$ we have $\arg(-i\times z)=\arg(i) = +i\pi/2$.

Your values are impossible, in that they are not a multiple of $2\pi$ out from the standard arguments.

You should be able to get the answer using these.

Comment: I made a change at about the same time you posted your answer.  But I don't quite follow your reasoning.  My reasoning is kind of sloppy.  I'm using the fact that $arg(-iz) = arg(-i)+arg(z)$ and trying to get both sides to agree.

Comment: That should be fine. $\arg(-i) = -\pi/2$ up to the usual $2\pi$ ambiguity, and for positive real $z$ the initial argument is $0$. Hence you get $-\pi/2$. Similarly $\pi + -\pi/2$ gives the other case.

Comment: My logic is just to fix the location of the one thing that matters, where the argument jumps, and then just choose values to be consistent with this.

Comment: And sorry, I must have not noticed the edit.

Comment: So the cut is along the negative imaginary axis and the argument of $-iz$ is $-\pi$ just to the right of cut and $\pi$ just to the left of the cut?

Comment: Yes (: It has to be these things up to $2\pi$ anyway, and continuity fixes their relative difference.

Answer (score 1):

Revisiting this question, I see no reason why we couldn't simply integrate the function $$f(z) = \frac{e^{iz} \log (z)}{z^{2}+4}$$ around the same contour with the branch cut in the same location.

The only extra step would be extracting the real part of the result.

By Jordan's lemma (or the estimation lemma), $ \int f(z) \, \mathrm dz $ vanishes along the upper half of the circle $|z|=R$ as $R \to \infty$.

Therefore,

$$ \begin{align} &\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{e^{ix} (\log |x| + i \pi)}{x^{2}+4} \, \mathrm  dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ix} \log (x)}{x^{2}+4} \, \mathrm  dx \\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-iu} (\log (u) + i \pi)}{u^{2}+4} \, \mathrm du + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ix} \log (x)}{x^{2}+4} \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\cos (x) - i \sin (x)) (\log (x) + i \pi)+ (\cos (x) + i \sin (x))\log (x)}{x^{2}+4}  \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2 \cos (x) \log (x)+ \pi \sin (x)}{x^{2}+4} \, \mathrm  dx + i \pi \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (x)}{x^{2}+4} \, \mathrm dx \\ &= 2 \pi i \ \text{Res}[f(z),2i] \\ &= 2 \pi i \left(\frac{e^{-2} (\log (2) + \frac{i \pi}{2})}{4i} \right) \\&= \frac{\pi \log (2)}{2e^{2}} + i \frac{\pi^{2}}{4e^{2}} .\end{align}$$

By equating the real parts on both sides of the equation,we arrive at the answer.